# What does it mean by attaching $0$-cells?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

Here is the definition of CW-decomposition of a topological pair $(X,A)$ given in Tom Dieck's Algebraic topology textbook p.205

> A sequence $A=X^{-1}\subset X^0\subset X^1 \subset ... \subset X^n$ is called a **CW-decomposition** of $(X,A)$ if it satisfies the followings:
>
> (1) $X=\bigcup_{n\geq 0} X^n$
>
> (2) $X^n$ is obtained from $X^{n-1}$ by attaching $n$-cells for $n\geq 0$
>
> (3) $X$ carries the colimit topology with respect to the family $(X^n)$.

I don't understand the hypothesis (2) when it is $n=0$. What does it mean by attaching $0$-cells?

Comment: You attach $D^n$ by a map from $\partial(D^n) \to X^{n-1}$. When $n=0$, $\partial(D^0) = \varnothing$. You're just taking the disjoint union with a point.

Comment: @MikeMiller All rigjt. Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching  $0$-cells to $A$ is taking the disjoint union of $A$ and a discrete topological space, for example a single point. Here is $1$-dim cell complex I have shown before: Fig 4.17 from [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html).

[image: joe]